# How to Insert a Azure Storage TableEntity with property longer than 32kB

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

When I have a class inheriting from `TableEntity` with the following constructor:

```
public CacheEntity(string cacheType, string key, string value) {
    this.PartitionKey = cacheType;
    this.RowKey = key;
    this.Value = value;
}
```

And I execute an insert operation as follows - when postsData is more than 32768 characters long:

```
CacheEntity entity = new CacheEntity(CacheType.CategoryPosts, cacheKey, postsData.Substring(0, 32769));
TableOperation insertCacheOperation = TableOperation.Insert(entity);
await cacheTable.ExecuteAsync(insertCacheOperation);
```

The `ExecuteAsync` method returns with Bad Request.

TableStorage documentation states that the maximum size of a [Row and Property is 1MiB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-scalability-targets#azure-table-storage-scale-targets)

I can successfully perform `ExecuteAsync` by truncating `postsData` to 32768, e.g.

```
CacheEntity entity = new CacheEntity(CacheType.CategoryPosts, cacheKey, postsData.Substring(0, 32768));
```

Is there a simple fix to allow more than 32KB of data in a TableEntity property?

Answer (score 1):

There's a maximum size for all properties that you've found, but each property also has a max size. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model):

> String values may be up to 64 KB in size. Note that the maximum number of characters supported is about 32 K or less.